# How to change display none input inside form?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button this name is manuel. When I click this button I want to change `display:none` property. Actually, its works but my element inside a form. When I click button form posted. I can't stop the post.

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="text">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Manuel</button><br>
  <input type="text" style="display:none;" id="hide1">
</div>
```

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("hide1").style.display = "block";
}
```

How to create input without form post?

Comment: Add `type="button"` on your `button` element, to make it a click button instead of a submit button.

Comment: What has this question to do with php, jquery or post?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change button `type="submit"` to `type="button"`, so you can do `display: none` function and if you want to submit the form you can do it with javascript.